# How to build a custom object selector based on an array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an array like this which keeps track of parent objects kind of like this:

```
var object = {
 'Shirt': {
    'Color':'Blue',
    'Size':'Large'
  },
  'Pants': {
    'Color':'White',
    'Size':'Medium',
  }
}
```

I'm writing a live object manipulation type thing and am keeping track of which object they are on.  The array looks like this:

```
var objectPath = ['Shirt', 'Color'];
```

Now I need to use that array to create a selector which allows me to manipulate data in the object path, eventually getting something like this.

```
selector = object['Shirt']['Color'];
```

That way I could do: `selector = 'Yellow'` and it would change the corresponding selection in the object.

I tried this but I can't get the array to translate into a selector:

```
objectPath.forEach(function(path, i) {
  selector += '[path]';
});
```

I know i'm making a new string and I can't figure out how to do it with an eval or something wierd like that.

Answer (score 3):

```
let obj = {
  'shirt': {
   'color': 'blue'
   }
},
ref = obj,
selectors = ['shirt', 'color']
newValue = 'yellow';
selectors.forEach(  (selector, index) => {
   if(index === selectors.length - 1) ref[selector] = newValue
   else ref = ref[selector];
})
console.log(obj.shirt.color)
```

If you want to manipulate the original object you're going to want to build up the path until the final property and then set that property to the new value.

Answer (score 2):

You can do [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) getting next nesting level on each 'path' iteration:

```js
const data = {
  one: {
    two: {
      three: {
        four: 'five'
     }
    }
  }
}

const path = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four']

const value = path.reduce((a, v) => a[v], data);

console.log(value)
```

You can even create a function which accepts 'path' array and the object, and returns a value or 'null' if the path is wrong:

```js
// function
const objSelector = o => pathArr => (Array.isArray(pathArr)) 
    ? pathArr.reduce((a, c) => (a[c] != null) ? a[c] : null, o)
    : null;

const data = {
  one: {
    two: {
      three: {
        four: 'five'
     }
    }
  }
}

const path = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four']

// use function
const value = objSelector(data)(path)

console.log(value)
```